# soap Signature verification error - PHP

Tags: php, soap, ws-security

im facing some problem with consuming webservices with wssecurity. im using robrichard's wse-php which is working fine for encryption ( if i miss any mandatory field , server will throw an error msg with Mandatory field missing which means it can decrypt the msg im sending ) .

But i have problem with the signature. the server is returning signature verification failed error and when we view the log it is showing as

```
[2015-06-24 11:16:33,061] WARN uuid:3f6c703f-05e6-85e8-6b62-a4fa343cd54f [org.apache.ws.security.validate.SignatureTrustValidator] 
[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)']: 
No Subject DN Certificate Constraints were defined. This could be a security issue
```

Comment: This is just a (unrelated) warning. Look elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your full code here. Did you have xml sample request ? Test with SoapUI first